# Prove that negative numbers are closed under addition.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, arithmetic

So here's what I'm thinking, but it feels too simple...

All negative numbers can be added to one another and remain negative. Consider the integers $x$ and $y$, where $x,y<0$. Then take $x+y$,

then I want to say that having both x and y be negative, means that their sum is negative, but that seems too simple... like I'm using the fact I'm trying to prove to prove it.

How should I finish this?

Comment: Are positive numbers closed under addition?

Comment: By number, do you mean *real* number, or *integer*, or something else?

Comment: The whole point of this exercise is to learn the expression "closed under operation", so the "nontrivial" bit (however trivial it may seem to *you*) is only in decoding what "closed under addition" means in this context. Your proof is right.

Comment: It is actually that simple. You only have to show that $x+y$ is negative assuming $x$ and $y$ are. This is in fact all you have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more formal way to state your (correct) intuition. Let $\mathbb{R}^-$ denote the set of negative reals and let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^-$.

Since $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^-$, we know $x,y<0$. Therefore,
$$
x+y < x+0 = x < 0,
$$
hence $x+y \in \mathbb{R}^-$.

Comment: Didn't you mean $x+0\color{red}=x$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner of course, typo, corrected